# Why files I add to my local repo do not appear on the remote?

Tags: git, github

I am very new to git. I created a repository (an empty one) in github and then cloned it.

```
git clone https://github.com/karthik82/my_misc_programs.git
```

This created an empty directory named `my_misc_programs` in my Linux system
After that I opened a file `Readme.txt` and put some dummy text into it.

then I did

```
git add Readme.txt
git commit
```

then I deleted the folder and did

```
git clone https://github.com/karthik82/my_misc_programs.git
```

but for some reason it did again checked out an empty directory.I couldn't find an empty file in it?

why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you forget to push it to github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try updating the url for your remote using `git remote set-url origin` to `ssh://git@github.com/karthik82/my_misc_programs.git` and putting your ssh key into the project. You should now be able to push and pull from the remote repository. If you need further help, do leave a comment.

Comment: There is no need to use a SSH URL  to push to github. Pushing with HTTPS works equally well.